# MAMP after Mavericks upgrade - reset databases?

Tags: mamp, osx-mavericks

After Mavericks upgrade, apps would not connect to MAMP.
Further inspection I can see the database has been reset to new. i.e. my databases and schemas have all vanished.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

Gone!

Since this was dev I didn't back up. Are there any recovery/suggestions or options you know of I can try before I start rebuilding?

Thanks in advance.

Kevin

Comment: MAMP stores database info in `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql` — I'm assuming you're using MySQL — the contents of this folder is your de facto database. When you upgrade **MAMP** (not OSX) I've noticed it will create backups of your old installation: you can check for old MAMP installations in your Applications folder like (this is a total guess) `/Applications/MAMP~backup/…` – otherwise, if you don't use TimeMachine or another backup system you're SOL. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you did a backup with TimeMachine before it was deleted you may recover it.

Comment: I know but I've had time machine turned off. But thanks anyway!!